# Suppose $g,h,a∈G$ such that $h=aga^{−1}$. Prove that the formula $x↦ax$ defines a bijection of sets $Fix_X(g)→Fix_X(h)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Consider a group $G$ acting on a set $X$. Suppose $g,h,a∈G$ such that $h=aga^{−1}$. Prove that the formula $x↦ax$ defines a bijection of sets $Fix_X(g)→Fix_X(h)$.

I know that $Fix_X(g)=\{x \in X: gx=x\}$. And correct me if I'm wrong, but it is obviously surjective because for any $y \in Fix_X(h)$ by just taking $a^{-1}y$ to get the value in $Fix_X(g)$.  However, I don't know how prove that it is injective.  So is this the correct approach (proving surjectivity and injectivity) and how would I prove injectivity?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a map is a bijection if and only if it is surjective and injective, and yes your method of showing surjectivity of the map $x\mapsto ax$ is correct. Furthermore,  injectivity of the map $x\mapsto ax$ isn't too difficult: If $x,y\in Fix_X(g)$ and $ax=ay$, then 
$$x=a^{-1}(ax)=a^{-1}(ay)=y.$$

Comment: I get the feeling that the fact that $h=aga^{-1}$ should be used because it is given information in the problem, but I don't know how it would relate to proving this simple map is bijective.  Thoughts?

Comment: @AndroidFish Any map of the form $x\mapsto bx$ for some $b\in G$ is injective on $X$ (hence on any subset thereof), since it has inverse given by the map $x\mapsto b^{-1}x$. The fact $h=aga^{-1}$ shows that the map $x\mapsto ax$ actually maps $Fix_X(g)$ into $Fix_X(h)$, and that this map is surjective with this domain and codomain.